# How can I tell what trailers I can attach?

Tags: snowrunner

I got to the Alaska garage yesterday, and found a trailer right nearby. I tried to hook it up so I could pull some cargo, but the game kept telling me that there was no suitable trailer nearby. I assume "suitable" is the keyword here, although my little pickup truck clearly has a trailer attachment point, this trailer *is* quite large.

How can I tell which trailers my truck can attach? Conversely, how can I tell what size truck a particular trailer needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct and easy way. You can drive your vehicle to a trailer store and browse through all of them - game will tell which can be attached.

- Scout trailers are only for scouts.
- Regular trailers are for any other type of vehicle, provided you don't have a semi-trailer already, and your truck bed it's too long (no way to know in advance,
  usually yellow crane and any bed blocks trailer)
- Semi-trailers require a special saddle mounted - regular for light semi-trailers,
  heavy for heavy semi-trailers